# Telerik RadScheduler cancel appointment move after Server-Side validation error

Tags: telerik, radscheduler, telerik-scheduler

I am using Telerik RadScheduler with Web Service binding.

When I drag an appointment to another timeslot, I do some client-side validation in `OnClientAppointmentMoveEnd`, and if that succeeds I set `args.set_cancel(true);`

It then hits my web service method `UpdateAppointment`.

My server side code within this web service call then does some additional validation based on a database query.

My question is - if this server side validation fails, how can I get the client-side appointment to move back to where it originated?  I can catch a status or message in `OnClientRequestFailed` but is there a way to cancel the move event after the web service call, or move the appointment back?

Answer (score 0):

I just found my own answer - 
After the `UpdateAppointment` web method is called, the scheduler will then call `GetAppointments` again, so the correct data should be reloaded on the client.

For others who might find this useful:

1. Do not throw an Exception in UpdateAppointment for a validation error. I set the error message in Session (couldn't find a way to pass it back from the Provider to the Web Method)
2. I created a class `MySchedulerResult` inheriting from `SchedulerOperationResult<AppointmentData>`, with an `ErrorMessage` property.
3. My `UpdateAppointment` Web Method returns this MySchedulerResult and assigns the Appointments returned from `Provider.UpdateAppointment` to it. It checks the Session to see if a validation error occurred, and sets the `ErrorMessage` property to this value if found.
4. My `OnClientRequestSuccess` method on the client side unpacks this result and pops up the error message if found.  Meanwhile the appointment data is getting reloaded and should have the changed appointment back in its original timeslot.

I found more info around the scheduler result class here: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/scheduler/web-service-binding/returning-extra-data-from-the-web-service